# How can I query for multiple properties not known in advance using Expando?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I'm making an application in which a user can create categories to put items in them. The items share some basic properties, but the rest of them are defined by the category they belong to. The problem is that both the category and it's special properties are created by the user.

For instance, the user may create two categories: books and buttons. In the 'book' category he may create two properties: number of pages and author. In the buttons category he may create different properties: number of holes and color.

Initially, I placed these properties in a JsonProperty inside the Item. While this works, it means that I query the Datastore just by specifying the category that I am looking for and then I have to filter the results of the query in the code. For example, if I'm looking for all the books whose author is Carl Sagan, I would query the Item class with category == books and the loop through the results to keep only those that match the author.

While I don't really expect to have that many items per category (probably in the hundreds, unlikely to get to one thousand), this looks inefficient. So I tried to use ndb.Expando to make those special properties *real* properties that are indexed. I did this, adding the corresponding special properties to the item when putting it to the Datastore. So if the user creates an Item in the 'books' category and previously created in that category the special property 'author', an Item is saved with the special property expando_author = author in it. It worked as I expected until this point (dev server).

The real problem though became visible when I did some queries. While they worked in the dev server, they created composite indexes for each special/expando property, even if the query filters were equality only. And while each category can have at most five properties, it is evident that it can easily get out of control.

Example query:

```
items = Item.query()
for p in properties:
    items = items.filter(ndb.GenericProperty(p)==properties[p])
items.fetch()
```

Now, since I don't know in advance what the properties will be (though I will limit it to 5), I can't build the indexes before uploading the application, and even if I knew it would probably mean having more indexes that I'm comfortable with. Is Expando the wrong tool for what I'm trying to do? Should I just keep filtering the results in the code using the JsonProperty? I would greatly appreciate any advice I can get.

PD. To make this post shorter I omitted a few details about what I did, if you need to know something I may have left out just ask in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider storing category's properties in a single list property prefixed with category property name.

Like  (*forget me I forgot exact Python syntax, switched to Go*)

```
class Item():
  props = StringListProperty()

book = Item(category='book', props=['title:Carl Sagan'])
button = Item(category='button', props=['wholes:5'])
```

Then you can do have a single composite index on `category+props` and do queries like this:

```
def filter_items(category, propName, propValue):
  Item.filter(Item.category == category).filter(Item.props==propName+':'+propValue)
```

And you would need a function on `Item` to get property values cleaned up from prop names.

Comment: Your idea sounds really good, I'll make an example with it and respond with the results.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works as expected. I'll now test it with bigger datasets, but it's definetly the way to go. Thanks again!